# Annotations in GeoDjango on many-to-many tables

Tags: django, annotations, postgis, geodjango

### short

I am trying to query a model `Foo` which has a many-to-many relationship to `Address` where addresses will be within a specified distance from a given point and sort results by ascending distance. Seems like annotation would be able to do this however I can't figure out how to do that in GeoDjango since it does not support geo annotations.

### longer

Here is the basic model structure I have:

```
# app name is bar
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    latlon = Models.PointFields(spatial_index=True)
    # other fields ommitted
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Address(models.Model):
    latlon = models.PointField(spatial_index=True)
    # other fields omitted
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Foo(models.Model):
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    # other fields omitted
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Using the above models I am able to construct a query which selects all Foo objects which have addresses within a specific distance from a specific point. For example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

new_york = Point(-73.98497, 40.75813)  # == Location.latlon

Foo.objects.filter(addresses__latlon__distance_lte=(new_york, Distance(mi=20)))
```

That generates a query something like:

```
SELECT
  "bar_foo"."id",
  ...
FROM "bar_foo"
  INNER JOIN "bar_foo_address"
    ON ("bar_foo"."id" = "bar_foo_address"."foo_id")
  INNER JOIN "bar_address"
    ON ("bar_foo_address"."address_id" = "bar_address"."id")
WHERE (ST_distance_sphere("bar_address"."latlon",ST_GeomFromEWKB(
           '\x0101000020e6100000aaf1d24d628052c096218e75715b4440' :: BYTEA)) <= 32186.88)
```

That works very well except I run into trouble if I want to sort the all foos by their distance from the given point. I tried something like:

```
(Foo
 .objects
 .filter(addresses__latlon__distance_lte=(new_york, Distance(mi=20)))
 .distance(Location.latlon)
 .order_by('distance'))

# produces

TypeError: ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields.
```

When I read some source code I tried to modify the query and yet still getting errors:

```
(Foo
 .objects
 .filter(addresses__latlon__distance_lte=(new_york, Distance(mi=20)))
 .distance(Location.latlon)
 .order_by('distance', field_name='addresses_latlon'))

# produces

ValueError: <django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField: latlon> not in self.query.related_select_cols
```

I guess this is related to a fact that `Address` and `Foo` have many-to-many relationship. Unfortunately regular annotations are not supported in GeoDjango so I cant do something like:

```
# hypothetical syntax
(Foo
 .objects
 .annotate(distance=DistanceAnnotation('addresses__latlon', new_york, unit='mi'))
 .filter(distance__lte=20)
 .order_by('distance'))

# which would generate

SELECT
  "bar_foo"."id",
  (ST_distance_sphere("bar_address"."latlon",ST_GeomFromEWKB(
           '\x0101000020e6100000aaf1d24d628052c096218e75715b4440' :: BYTEA)) as distance,
  ...
FROM "bar_foo"
  INNER JOIN "bar_foo_address"
    ON ("bar_foo"."id" = "bar_foo_address"."foo_id")
  INNER JOIN "bar_address"
    ON ("bar_foo_address"."address_id" = "bar_address"."id")
WHERE distance <= 32186.88)
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

So the question is how can I do do regular annotation using existing API? Or maybe some other way I can accomplish the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Distance annotation was implemented in 1.9

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance

> Distance
>
> class Distance(expr1, expr2, spheroid=None, **extra) Availability:
>   MySQL, PostGIS, Oracle, SpatiaLite
>
> Accepts two geographic fields or expressions and returns the distance
>   between them, as a Distance object. On MySQL, a raw float value is
>   returned when the coordinates are geodetic.
>
> (...)
>
> In the following example, the distance from the city of Hobart to
>   every other PointField in the AustraliaCity queryset is calculated:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
>>> pnt = AustraliaCity.objects.get(name='Hobart').point
>>> for city in AustraliaCity.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('point', pnt)):
...     print(city.name, city.distance)
Wollongong 990071.220408 m
Shellharbour 972804.613941 m
Thirroul 1002334.36351 m
...
```